# Run checks on Items from tables in Sqlite and python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have two tables below:

```
----------
Items  | QTY
----------
sugar  | 14
mango  | 10
apple  | 50
berry  | 1

----------
Items  |QTY
----------
sugar  |10
mango  |5
apple  |48
berry  |1
```

I use the following query in python to check difference between the QTY of table one and table two.

```
 cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("select s.Items, s.qty - t.qty as quantity from Stock s join Second_table t on s.Items = t.Items;")
    remaining_quantity = cur.fetchall()
```

I'm a bit stuck on how to go about what I need to accomplish. I need to check the difference between the quantity of table one and table two, if the quantity (difference) is under 5 then for those Items I want to be able to store this in another table column with the value 1 if not then the value will be 0 for those Items. How can I go about this?

Edit:

I have attempted this like by looping through the rows and if the column value is less than 5 then insert into the new table with the value below. :

```
 for row in remaining_quantity:
        print(row[1])
        if((row[1]) < 5):
            cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO check_quantity_tb VALUES (select distinct s.Items, s.qty, s.qty - t.qty as quantity, 1 from Stock s join Second_table t on s.Items = t.Items'), row)
        print(row)
```

But I get a SQL syntax error not sure where the error could be :/

Comment: Looks like you will have to loop over the rows, check the quantity, then store them in your other table with the appropriate value.  Seems quite straightforward actually... What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: okay I got stuck as I got as far as getting the data from two different data sources and putting them into tables. I have looped over the rows, checked the quanity but have problems with inserting them with the appropriate value. Would appreciate any help, see above. Thanks

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers the select statement works if I use it without the insert but not sure why it shows syntax error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First modify your first query so you retrieve all relevant infos and don't have to issue subqueries later:

```
readcursor = conn.cursor()
readcursor.execute(
  "select s.Items, s.qty, s.qty - t.qty as remain " 
  "from Stock s join Second_table t on s.Items = t.Items;"
  )
```

Then use it to update your third table:

```
writecursor = conn.cursor()
for items, qty, remain in readcursor:
    print(remain)

    if remain < 5:
        writecursor.execute(
           'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO check_quantity_tb VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', 
            (items, qty, remain, 1) 
            )

conn.commit()
```

Note the following points:

1/ We use two distinct cursor so we can iterate over the first one while wrting with the second one. This avoids fetching all results in memory, which can be a real life saver on huge datasets

2/ when iterating on the first cursor, we unpack the rows into their individual componants. This is called "tuple unpacking" (but actually works for most sequence types):

```
>>> row = ("1", "2", "3")
>>> a, b, c = row
>>> a
'1'
>>> b
'2'
>>> c
'3'
```

3/ We let the db-api module do the proper sanitisation and escaping of the values we want to insert. This avoids headaches with escaping / quoting etc and protects your code from SQL injection attacks (not that you might have one here, but that's the correct way to write parameterized queries in Python).

NB : since you didn't not post your full table definitions nor clear specs - not even the full error message and traceback - I only translated your code snippet to something more sensible (avoiding the costly and useless subquery, which migh *or not* be the cause of your error). I can't garantee it will work out of the box, but at least it should put you back on tracks.

NB2 : you mentionned you had to set the last col to either 1 or 0 depending on `remain` value. If that's the case, you want your loop to be:

```
writecursor = conn.cursor()
for items, qty, remain in readcursor:
    print(remain)

    flag = 1 if remain < 5 else 0
    writecursor.execute(
           'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO check_quantity_tb VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', 
            (items, qty, remain, flag) 
            )

conn.commit()
```

If you instead only want to process rows where remain < 5, you can specify it directly in your first query with a where clause.

Comment: Thanks for this you're great, but I am getting an error when running on the line of (items, qty, remain, flag), the error shows sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error. Any ideas?

Comment: It works :), I had to change the %s to question marks, thanks.

Comment: Sorry my bad - I most often use MySQL which (well the python connector) uses "%s" as placeholders.  I fixed it in the answer.